# Linq command to group by date - how to group

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create an Iqueryable method which returns the number of connections to a service for each day. this data is read from a SQL Server database.

Here is ConnectionItem class

```
public class ConnectionItem
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfConnections { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my iqueryable

```
private IQueryable<ConnectionItem> ListItems(DataContext dataContext)
{
    return dataContext.Connections
        .Join(dataContext.Configurations,
            connections => connections.ConfigID,
            config => config.ConfigID,
            (connections, config) => new { cx = connections, cf = config })
        .Join(dataContext.Users,
            config => config.cf.UserID,
            users => users.UserID,
            (config, users) => new { cf = config, su = users})
            .Where(q => q.su.AccountEventID == 123 && q.cf.cx.Successful == true)
            .GroupBy(g => g.cf.cx.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString())
            .Select(s => new ConnectionItem
            {
                CreatedDate = ????,
                NumberOfConnections = ????
            });
}
```

How do I access the grouped date value and the number of items per group?

Also, is there an easier way to write this kind of statements? I am not 100% sure on how the aliases cx,cf etc work.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Try just call `{CreateDate=s.Key, NumberOfConnections=s.Count()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `Date` portion of the `DateTime` objects.  The `Date` property simply drops the time part.  You're converting your dates to strings so you're losing the fidelity of a DateTime object.

```
var eventId = 123;
return dataContext.Connections.Join(dataContext.Configurations,
        conn => conn.ConfigID,
        cfg => cfg.ConfigID,
        (conn, cfg) => new { conn, cfg })
    .Join(dataContext.Users,
        x => x.cfg.UserID,
        u => u.UserID,
        (x, u) => new { x.conn, u })
    .Where(x => x.conn.Successful && x.u.AccountEventID == eventId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.conn.CreatedDate.Date)
    .Select(g => new ConnectionItem
    {
        CreatedDate = g.Key,
        NumberOfConnections = g.Count(),
    });
```

The above could be more nicely expressed using query syntax.

```
var eventId = 123;
return
    from conn in dataContext.Connections
    join cfg in dataContext.Configurations on conn.ConfigID equals cfg.ConfigID
    join u in dataContext.Users on cfg.UserID equals u.UserID
    where conn.Successful && u.AccountEventID == eventId
    group 1 by conn.CreatedDate.Date into g
    select new ConnectionItem
    {
        CreatedDate = g.Key,
        NumberOfConnections = g.Count(),
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.GroupBy` linq method returns an `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>`, which is basically a List with a `Key` property that you've just grouped by.

So here

```
Select(s => new ConnectionItem
        {
            CreatedDate = ????,
            NumberOfConnections = ????
        });
```

Your iterating through a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>>`so you can do this

```
Select(s => new ConnectionItem
        {
            CreatedDate = s.Key
            NumberOfConnections = s.Count()
        });
```

**edited** as per comment I realized your looking for the number not an actual list

Answer (score 0):

Just call `s.Key` and `s.Count()` ,You can  get it like:

```
private IQueryable<ConnectionItem> ListItems(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        return dataContext.Connections
            .Join(dataContext.Configurations,
                connections => connections.ConfigID,
                config => config.ConfigID,
                (connections, config) => new {cx = connections, cf = config})
            .Join(dataContext.Users,
                config => config.cf.UserID,
                users => users.UserID,
                (config, users) => new {cf = config, su = users})
            .Where(q => q.su.AccountEventID == 123 && q.cf.cx.Successful == true)
            .GroupBy(g => g.cf.cx.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString())
            .Select(s => new ConnectionItem
            {
                CreatedDate = s.Key,
                NumberOfConnections = s.Count()
            });
    }
```

> The group clause returns a sequence of IGrouping
>   objects that contain zero or more items that match the key value for
>   the group. For example, you can group a sequence of strings according
>   to the first letter in each string. In this case, the first letter is
>   the key and has a type char, and is stored in the Key property of each
>   IGrouping object. The compiler infers the type of the
>   key.

[Group clause docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)